# Clustering by time in Cassandra - CQL3

Tags: cassandra, timestamp, cluster-analysis, cql3

I have a question on wide rows, clustering, manual indexes etc... I am hoping someone can assist here. CQL version is 3 and Cassandra is 2.0.1;

Let's say, I have CF 'products'

```
    id timeuuid

    location varchar

    shopname varchar

    expiry timestamp

    count int

    PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

I want to be able to select products at specific location ordered by expiry. Therfore create register like:

```
CF 'id_register_by_loc_expy'

    location varchar

    expiry timestamp

    id timeuuid

    PRIMARY KEY (location,expiry,id)
```

and want to select products at specific shopname ordered by expiry. Then create:

```
CF 'id_register_by_shopname_expy'

    shopname vachar

    expiry timestamp

    id timeuuid

    PRIMARY KEY (shopname,expiry,id)
```

This is so I can do efficient queries/slicing as follows:

1.select id from id_reg_by_loc_expy where location = 'x';   // [naturally ordered by expiry]

2.select id from id_reg_by_loc_expy where location = 'x' and expiry > 't1' and expiry < 't2';

3.select * from products where id = 'id';

and;

4.select id from id_reg_by_shop_exp where shopname = 'y';    // [naturally ordered by expiry]

and;

5.select id from id_reg_by_shop_count where shopname = 'y';
  // [naturally ordered by count]

etc..

What if the clustering key needs to change and I need to reorder the entries on these particular rows in the register(s).

Issues I have are:

1. reinserting with a new expiry (or count) results in new Primary Key therefore doesn't update my old entry.
2. I can't "update .. set expiry = 'x2' where ..." since expiry is part of primary key.
3. Inserting with new primary key then deleting old one is a bad option due to the tombstoning limitation.

Things I have tried are:

1. CF 'id_reg_by_loc_expy'

   ```
   location varchar

   expiry timestamp

   id timeuuid

   otherSecondaryIndex varchar

   PRIMARY KEY (location,id)
   ```

But;

a. this does not take advantage of Cassandra's stored sorted functionality. I expect to have many products in each row, and want to avoid needing to search the entire row; and

b. it turns out that I can't actually do a query like the following anyway:

(i)select id from id_reg_... where location='x' order by dtg asc;

Bad Request: ORDER BY with 2ndary indexes is not supported.

```
Or
```

(ii)select id from id_reg_... where location='x' and expiry > 't1' and expiry < 't2';

Bad Request: No indexed columns present in by-columns clause with Equal operator

Although I 'can' do this:

(iii)select id from id_reg_... where location='x' and otherSecIndex='y' and expiry > 't1' and expiry < 't2';

** note that this requires me to force 'allow filtering' and seems poor design to include another secondary index simply to allow this query.. i.e. a query of which I'm less interested in than the 'order by' query anyway.

2. Using timeuuid in lieu of timestamp for the expiry. Even if this comes to work which I can't find a way, it doesn't help my 'ordering by count' intentions.

Am I missing something fundamental here? Is the answer that I need to go ahead with all the tombstone mitigation techniques? or do some of the ordering in my application?

Cheers,
Tim

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to get sorting without having the sorted column be part of the primary key.  Cassandra doesn't do sorting at query time.

Do you expect to change expiration stamps multiple times per product_id?  If not, then tombstones should not be a huge problem, especially if your rows are really as small as you're describing them.  You can tweak relevant settings such as `gc_grace_seconds` (how long tombstones hang around for) to make sure they match your operational demands and capacity.

If you plan to update expiration times very frequently, then my first instinct is that it's a pattern that cannot be easily handled without some measurement and handtuning to arrive at a stable configuration.  If you start to get swamped with tombstones, you may have to resort to a major compaction schedule to remove accumulating tombstones effectively.

The bottom line is that any storage pattern with queue-like semantics is non-trivial to implement in a scalable fashion in Cassandra.  At least that's my intuition.